# TYPO3 meta description - Text crop

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-11.x

here is the normal typoscript code for the Example like the Description:

```
page {
  meta {
    description = TEXT
    description {
      field = og_description // description
      crop = 160| |1
    }
  }
}
```

How can i add a crop for the description Text?

Thanks all

Comment: please describe more in detail what you expect and what you get

Comment: i need a text crop for the TYPO3 page.meta.description

Comment: as `page.meta.<string>` has [stdWrap functionality](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#meta) your code should work and [crop](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html?highlight=crop#crop) any data after 160 characters.

Comment: but it dont work :(

Comment: then try `meta.<string>.stdWrap.crop` or use `meta.<string>.cObject = TEXT` to get a clean TEXT object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With activated EXT:seo the tags are first set by PHP and after that, the TypoScript config is handled. The TypoScript configuration does *not* replace existing tags by default. So tags that have been set via PHP will *not* be overwritten.

If you'd like to change this default behavior, you have to use `replace` in TypoScript configuration (-> "[MetaTag API > TypoScript and PHP](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Seo/MetaTagApi.html#metatagapi-configuration)":

```
page.meta {
    description = TEXT
    description.value = Override the pages description
    description.replace = 1
}
```

Comment: 1 there was no question about replacing. 2 you example is incorrect as `meta` is no COA but just an array of strings.

Comment: 1) Sebastian tries to set `description`. In combination with EXT:SEO you have to replace it if you wanna set it via TS - independently if you already *know* it and are not asking for that ;-) 2) Your comment is wrong. Please have a look at the example. `meta` is still an array, but `description` is used as cObject. Where do you see a `COA`? And if you don't trust me: try the example! It's working ;-)

Comment: maybe with an extension. with pure TYPO3 you get `<meta name="description" content="TEXT" />` (`meta` is an array of strings instead of an array of objects)

Comment: As written above "With activated EXT:seo" (which *is* pure TYPO3). Of course, this behavior would be the same if any third extension sets meta.description via MetaTag API.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ, do we want to clean up here? Or do you want to show me the  `COA` which makes my example incorrect?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ, you're rejecting the right approach because you think the example is "incorrect". But you don't provide any proof of that (even when asked) - but then you post that solution as your own answer. That's pretty rude, isn't it?

Comment: hi, thanks, the replace = 1 is the solution ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Julian mentioned: if you want to modify an existing meta tag definition you need to use `replace` (even if you only modify the existing definition)

If you only want to crop the existing text your code should be:

```
page {
  meta {
    description {
      crop = 160| |1
      replace = 1
    }
  }
}
```

If you also want to change the fields you could use
(my default is `description.field = description`):

```
page {
  meta {
    description {
      field = og_description // description
      crop = 160| |1
      replace = 1
    }
  }
}
```

**But don't use**: `description = TEXT` as this will set the value `TEXT` to the meta tag

Comment: `description = TEXT` doesn't change anything (whether with or without MetaTag API).

Comment: hi, thanks, the replace = 1 is the solution ;) Thanks.